# Unexpected output while sending a pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, g++

So, I was trying out a few things and decided to intentionally remove a return statement from a function supposed to return an int.

My guess was, that the function would return a garbage value, and the program would terminate normally.

However, the program got stuck in an infinite loop. Is this a bug ? Or am I missing something?

The compiler, I am using is G++, GCC Version 9.3.0 with GNU-G++-17, and GNU-G++-14

```cpp
#pragma GCC optimize("O1")
#include <iostream>

int f(int* &a)
{
    std::cout << *a;
    // return 0;
}

void solve()
{
    int *p = new int{7};
    f(p);
    delete p;
}

int main()
{
    solve();
}
```

Compiler Output

```
777777777777777777777777777777777...(until it crashes...)
```

An ideone link for the above code : https://ideone.com/j9m24N

PS:- It happens with pragma for `O1`, `O2`, `O3`, `Ofast` but not with `O0`

And I know that we should supply a return statement, but what I am interested in knowing is the reason why we are getting this output.

Comment: Why-quesion is meaningless in case of the undefined behavior. "Is this a bug?" Yes, this is a bug in the program.

Comment: Despite the UB it is still interesting how [GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wb3Yr5qeG) choses to optimise this. It basically creates the same issue that you would have if you didn't use `break;` in `switch-case` statements, but between the two functions here. While not particularly useful because UB still interesting

Comment: @Lala5th No `return`, no asm `ret` command, `f` falls to `solve` getting the infinit recursion.

Comment: This seems to be handled better in `clang`, where instead of not compiling (like msvc), or with optimistaions not generating the return (like you saw with gcc, still don't know why only with optimisations turned on though), it generates [`ud2`(undefined instruction)](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html), so that the program cannot fall through.

Comment: @S.M. Weird how it only does it with optimisations on though. Not sure if that is intended or just some weird play between the optimiser and how implicit return statements in `void` returning functions are handled in gcc

Comment: yeah, its probably because of the `ret` command in assembly, check out the assembly produced by the code

Comment: 3 compilers report that `f` must return a value, clang and gcc just warn, MSVC errors -live - https://godbolt.org/z/Y8MW7zM36  Fix it and move on analysing UB is pointless.

Comment: I am curious about 1 thing : your function ```int f(int* &a)``` is supposed to return an integer. But, you comment out the statement ```return 0``` at the end of that function. Do you have a compile error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bug ?

Yes. This is a bug in your program.

> Or am I missing something?

Yes. You're missing a `return` statement.

> why we are getting this output.

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined. This explains all that a C++ programmer needs to know about the behaviour of the program, and it is all that we can know within the limits of the C++ language.

> My guess was, that the function would ...

You cannot assume that there would be any particular behaviour when the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

To undrstand what a particular compiled program does, you need to read assembly that was produced by the compiler. I was able to reproduce the behaviour and here is a simplification:

```
f(int*&):
        ... instructions ...
solve():
        ... instructions ...
        call    f(int*&)
```

The function `f` contains no `ret` instruction or any other instruction that would jump somewhere else. Thus, the execution continues to the next instruction that happens to be the first instruction of the function `solve`. At the end of `solve`, we call `f` which is where we started. We end up with infinite recursion.